# csv.DictReader takes 10x more space

Tags: python, csv

I'm reading a csv file which is about 1 GB but it winds up taking over 10 GB of memory. Since DictReader returns an iterator over dicts, each of which has the elements of the header string encoded as keys, I can imagine `lines` taking up twice as much space (~1 GB) but ten times as much? This confuses me.

```
import csv

def readeverything(filename):
     thefile = open(filename)
     reader = csv.DictReader(thefile, delimiter='\t')
     lines = []

     for datum in reader:
         lines.append(datum)
     thefile.close()

     return lines
```

The size of the raw string is actually smaller than the size of the parsed dict. I found this out using `sys.getsizeof` on the first line in the file and on the first record read by `csv.DictReader`. Therefore, the strict size of the dictionary does not account for the exponential explosion of memory usage when reading the CSV.

Comment: Python objects have quite a few metadata, it being a dynamic language. Do not keep all the data in a list at once as you do now.

Comment: I want to sort the lines in the file and then apply other functions based on the sorted list.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev just addressed the claim that this is a duplicate question. If you'd like, I can back it up with some numbers but this is probably meaningless without the original data.

Comment: @gideonite: `dict`s have a lot of overhead that `list` and `tuple` do not. If you want to reduce memory overhead dramatically, you can read the header to get the list of column names, and use it to create a `collections.namedtuple` type with appropriate fields. You can then use a regular `csv.reader` to read, wrap the reader with `map(mynamedtuple._make, myreader)` to convert to `namedtuple`s with attributes matching the columns. If necessary, you can call `._asdict()` on them when you actually use them to (temporarily) convert back to an (ordered) `dict`.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll try one of those then. If I'm not mistaken, the dict used less memory than the original string as reported by `sys.getsizeof`.

Comment: @gideonite: `sys.getsizeof` doesn't recurse, so it's only telling you the overhead of the `dict` structure storing the references to keys and values, not the size occupied by the keys and values themselves. Similarly, most user-defined objects won't include the cost of their `__dict__`, which is where all the actual attributes are stored, making them seem much smaller than they really are.